# Call sqlcmd commands in stored procedure code

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcmd, openrowset

Because of Linked Server is not easy to send openrowset query I connect to remote Sql Server directly via SQLCMD mode. But this is Ok using Query Analyzer. When I put code to stored procedure I cannot even save it:

```
:Connect x.x.x.x -U sa -P password
select *
from  openrowset('VFPOLEDB','\\share\db\s_object.dbf';'';
    '','SELECT *  FROM s_object where i_class=21 order by 1')
```

> Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio has a [sqlcmd compatible mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx). The ancient Query Analyzer has a similar mode, but you have to talk to old folk to see how to enable it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlcmd mode `:connect` syntax is valid in SSMS and QA when sqlcmd mode is enabled, but it will always be a **client side** command, executed by SSMS or QA itself and never sent to the engine. As such by no way it can be embedded on a server side module, like a stored procedure. If you really mean stored procedure then no wonder the syntax error...

Comment: I am sorry for very long delay after your detailed response - I was looking for any other solution to implement openrowset/openquery over Linked Server. Actually you answered my question and I need to open another tread to find solution for that.